# How do I move a file into a folder in Divshot?

Tags: file-structure, divshot

For example, I want to move app.css into the css folder I created. Drag-and-drop doesn't work. Right-click > **Move** doesn't seem to work either...it only opens the file name for renaming, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Rename" feature to move directories. So if I have a file `example.png` that I want to move into the images directory, I just need to make the filename `images/example.png` and a directory will automatically be created.

Hope that helps!